# How to automatically overwrite a file with the same name?

Tags: python, excel, file, overwrite

When running this code I always get a dialog box asking if I want to replace the file with the same name ("summary3.xlsx"). How can I automatically overwrite the file with the same name without having to select "yes" from the dialogue box every time I run the code to overwrite it?

```
from win32com import client
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Table1.docx")
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\example.xlsx")
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:D10").Copy()    
wdRange = doc.Content
wdRange.Collapse(0)
wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, True, False) 
book.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\summary3.xlsx")
book.Close()
excel.Quit()
doc.SaveAs(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\TableOne.docx")
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: why not delete the original file before `SaveAs`..

Comment: that's smart. Thanks!

Comment: According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas), `SaveAs` method has a parameter called `ConflictResolution` that controls exactly what you need. The value of the parameter would be `xlLocalSessionChanges` in your case